# The fixed point A has coordinates (8, -6, 5) and the variable point P has coordinates (t, t, 2t). Show that AP² = 6t² - 24t + 125.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I've never encountered such a question before; it was included in as a sub-question on a different topic.

I think I'd understand how I'd get 6t^2 and 125 (square then sum the individual numbers in each coordinate) but no idea how to get -24t. What is the correct way of approaching/doing this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The distance between the points $A$ and $P$ is given by the Pythagorean formula

$$\sqrt{(8-t)^2+(-6-t)^2+(5-2t)^2}\;,$$

so the square of the distance is

$$(8-t)^2+(-6-t)^2+(5-2t)^2\;.$$

What do you get when you simplify this polynomial?

Comment: Thank you. I had originally attempted to try something vaguely similar to this (squared each coordinate of P before trying to find the distance).

Comment: @Wk_of_Angmar: You’re welcome.